# What is the general approach when designing python libraries which require other python libraries?

Tags: python

I've created an application in Python 2.7 and PySide. Since this application is rather large, I had to create a number of custom libraries. These libraries sometimes needs to call methods from other custom libraries and so I made the classes in the libraries inherit other libraries' classes. This, however, sometimes ended in inheritance resolution issues, causing me to have to create redundant and non-elegant solutions as a workaround.

Now, I'm in the progress of rewriting the application from scratch and I would like to make sure I design my custom libraries in such a way that they are not dependant on inheritance. What would be the generally best approach?

I'm thinking I should use `with`:

```
from libs import envlib
from libs import diskoplib
from libs import dblib

class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Something, self).__init__()

    def do_something(self):
        names = None
        filepath = None
        id = None
        with envlib.Query() as e,
             diskoplib.Query() as d,
             dblib.Query() as db:

            id = e.get_opened_file_id()
            names = db.get_names()
            filepath = d.get_filepath()

        print id, names, filepath # ready to be used for something
```

Would this generally be a good approach or is there a reason why this may not be a good approach?

Comment: What is it that you think the `with` (context manager) as gaining you? If you're concerned about coupling, why not inject the `Query` instances (e.g. `def do_something(self, env_query, db_query, file_query):` or whatever)?

Comment: I don't see how this is much of an improvement on `import envlib.Query as e` and then `self._e_query = e(); e.get_opened_file_id()`. As @jonrsharpe said passing instances is a better way to decouple.

Comment: @JohnKeyes `Query` is class of submodule `envlib`, so I would get an `ImportError: No module named Query` - but I guess I could do `import envlib` followed by  `self._e_query = envlib.Query()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was thinking that the `with` context manager would make `e`, `d`, `db` get garbage collected outside of the `with` and thus saving a bit of memory. However it seems this this is not the case, and also, your and John's suggestion makes for less code which is easier to read.

Comment: @fredrik Okay, I was just showing similarities is all. I don't see what `with` really gives you here. Good luck.

Comment: That isn't really related to inheritance or coupling. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I was unclear. Your suggestion was great. I'm going to use it. If you wish, create an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating class attributes was a better idea. Thanks @jonsharpe and @JohnKeyes for the suggestions.

```
from libs import envlib
from libs import diskoplib
from libs import dblib

class Something(object):

    # Class attributes
    _e = envlib.Query()
    _d = diskoplib.Query()
    _db = dblib.Query()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Something, self).__init__()

    def do_something(self):
        id = self._e.get_opened_file_id()
        filepath = self._d.get_filepath()
        names = self._db.get_names()

        print id, names, filepath # ready to be used for something
```